# PHP Parallel processing for a Metasearch Engine

Tags: php, parallel-processing, meta-search

I have developed a metasearch engine and one of the optimisations I would like to make is to process the search APIs in parallel. Imagine that results are retrieved from Search Engine A in 0.24 seconds, SE B in 0.45 Seconds and from SE C in 0.5 seconds. With other overheads the metasearch engine can return aggregated results in about 1.5 seconds, which is viable. Now what I would like to do is to send those requests in parallel rather than in series, as at present, and get that time down to under a second. I have investigated exec, forking, threading and all, for various reasons, have failed. Now I have only spent a day or two on this so I may have missed something. Ideally i would like to implement this on a WAMP stack on my development machine (localhost) and see about implementing on a Linux webserver thereafter. Any help appreciated.

Let's take a simple example: say we have two files we want to run simultaneously. File 1:

```
<?php
// file1.php
echo 'File 1 - Test 1'.PHP_EOL;
$sleep = mt_rand(1, 5);
echo 'Start Time: '.date("g:i:sa").PHP_EOL;
echo 'Sleep Time: '.$sleep.' seconds.'.PHP_EOL;
sleep($sleep);
echo 'Finish Time: '.date("g:i:sa").PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Now, imagine file two is the same... the idea is that if run in parallel the command line output for the times should be the same, for example:

```
File 1 - Test 1
Start Time: 9:30:43am
Sleep Time: 4 seconds.
Finish Time: 9:30:47am
```

But whether I use exec, popen or whatever, I just cannot get this to work in PHP!

Comment: All signs point to `exec()`

Comment: Let's take a simple example: say we have two files we want to run simultaneously. File 1:
<?php
 // Test file 1
 echo 'File 1 - Test 1'.PHP_EOL;
 $sleep = mt_rand(1, 5);
 echo 'Start Time: '.date("g:i:sa").PHP_EOL;
 echo 'Sleep Time: '.$sleep.' seconds.'.PHP_EOL;
 sleep($sleep);
 echo 'Finish Time: '.date("g:i:sa").PHP_EOL;
?>

Comment: @ConorRyan Check the updated answer - I included a working example.

Answer (score 1):

There is one viable approach. Make a cli php file that gets in arguments what it have to do and returns whatever result is produced serialized.

In your main app you may `popen` as many of these workers as you need and then in a simple loop collect the outputs:

**[edit]** I used your worker example, just had to `chmod +x` and add a `#!/usr/bin/php` line on top:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo 'File 1 - Test 1'.PHP_EOL;
$sleep = mt_rand(1, 5);
echo 'Start Time: '.date("g:i:sa").PHP_EOL;
echo 'Sleep Time: '.$sleep.' seconds.'.PHP_EOL;
sleep($sleep);
echo 'Finish Time: '.date("g:i:sa").PHP_EOL;
?>
```

also modified the run script a little bit - ex.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$pha=array();
$res=array();
$pha[1]=popen("./file1.php","r");
$res[1]='';
$pha[2]=popen("./file2.php","r");
$res[2]='';
while (list($id,$ph)=each($pha)) {
    while (!feof($ph))
        $res[$id].=fread($ph,8192);
    pclose($ph);
}
echo $res[1].$res[2];
```

here is the result, when tested in cli (its the same when ex.php is called from web, but paths to file1.php and file2.php should be fixed):

> ```
> $ time ./ex.php 
> File 1 - Test 1
> Start Time: 11:00:33am
> Sleep Time: 3 seconds.
> Finish Time: 11:00:36am
> File 2 - Test 1
> Start Time: 11:00:33am
> Sleep Time: 4 seconds.
> Finish Time: 11:00:37am
>
> real  0m4.062s
> user  0m0.040s
> sys   0m0.036s
> ```

As seen in the result one script takes 3 seconds to execute and the other takes 4. Both run for 4 seconds together in parallel.

**[end edit]**

In this way the slow operation will run in parallel, you will only collect the result in serial.

Finally it will take (the slowest worker time)+(time for collecting) to execute. Since the time for collecting the results and time to unserialize, etc., may be ignored you get all data for the time of the slowest request.

As a side note you may try to use the `igbinary` serialiser that is much faster than the built-in one.

As noted in comments:

`worker.php` is executed outside of the web request and you have to pass all its state via arguments. Passing arguments may also be a problem to handle all escaping, security and etc., so not-effective but simple way is to use base64.

A major drawback in this approach is that it is not easy to debug.

It can be further improved by using `stream_select` instead of `fread` and also collecting data in parallel.

Comment: the worker code will not run in the same context as the application. This will make it impossible debug the application at once and requires to communicate the required application context from and to the worker script. also exception and/or error handling will need attention to get it working (simulated, using return codes and messages -> weird). `socket_select()` is *the* way to go

Comment: I thought about this. I think now that the advantage of `socket_select()` depends on the time it takes to connect to the server. If it takes long, your solution might be better. I must admit this to keep sportsmanship. If you are interested in a ready-to use worker solution have a look at [Gearman](http://gearman.org/)

Comment: Sorry if my comment were offensive. don't take it personal it was just because I like `socket_select()|stream_select()` and think that they are nice in many cases. Take your answer for example. You can use `stream_select()` to read from all workers in parallel (if you start the process with `proc_open()`).. However, because the connection time is cummulative in my answer unlike yours I would finally say yours is the best solution. +1

Comment: @bbonev Hmm, I have not been able to implement that solution... for one thing there is an undefined offset... but the gearman solution is worth investigating...

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`socket_select()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.socket-select.php). Doing so, only the connection time would be cummulative as you can read from the sockets in parralel. This will give you a *big* performance boost.